# Set size of InlineUIContainer?

Tags: silverlight, layout, size, textblock, inlineuicontainer

I wrapped a `TextBlock` in an `InlineUIContainer` inside a `RichTextBox`, its content is bound to an external multi-line `TextBox` that the user updates on the spot.

What happens is the `InlineUIContainer`'s size doesn't expand or shrink as needed, it's a static size, I need it to be extended according to the size of the inner `TextBlock` (I've tested the size of the `TextBlock` and it does resize according to its content).

Any way to do this? Of course a XAMLy way is preferred, even more verbose.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did an ugly and hacky workaround, hope to be able to replace it soon.

I made another property in the ViewModel, that returns:

```
string.IsNullOrWhitespace(comments) ? 
  string.Empty : 
  string.Format("Comments:{1}{0}{1}", comments, Environment.NewLine);
```

It works but is nasty.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if it's a Silverlight thing, but trying out this in Kaxaml works (typing in the Textbox expands it):

```
<RichTextBox IsDocumentEnabled="true">
  <FlowDocument>
    <Paragraph>
      <Run>cool </Run>
      <InlineUIContainer><TextBox>woohoo</TextBox></InlineUIContainer>
      <Run>stuff</Run>
    </Paragraph>
  </FlowDocument>
</RichTextBox>
```

Comment: Expands it horizontally (i.e. when adding new lines)?

Comment: try it out, this answer is supposed to give you some reference for what you might be doing wrong, or reference for me trying to figure out what your problem is, because as I stated this works for me!

Comment: The `IsDocumentEnabled` property is not implemented in Silverlight, the issue still persists.